# Postgresql - Autoincrement ID

Tags: postgresql-13

I am using Postgresql v13.4 and I want to update an existing and have got some problems to keep the existing ID when there is a conflict.

I am creating the following table which is successfully shown in Postgresql:

```
 query = """
    DROP SEQUENCE user_id_seq cascade;
    Create sequence user_id_seq;    
    CREATE TABLE customers3 (        
    "customer_id" bigint PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('user_id_seq'),    
    "name" VARCHAR,
    "age" Integer,
    "insdat" Integer NOT NULL,
    "upddat" Integer NOT NULL,
    constraint test unique(name)
 )
"""
```

Once I insert the data the output is following:

```
####################################
## Insert data
(0, 'Paul', 42, 2021, 2021)
(1, 'Peter', 23, 2021, 2021)
(2, 'Mary', 33, 2021, 2021)
```

Now I want to insert the case which results into the FIRST error:

```
 INSERT INTO customers3 (name, age, insdat, upddat) VALUES ('Adam', 24, 2022, 2022)
         ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT test do update set  age = 24, upddat = 2022;
 Database connection failed due to (psycopg2.errors.UniqueViolation) duplicate key  value violates unique constraint "customers3_pkey"  
 DETAIL:  Key (customer_id)=(1) already exists.
```

I would like to insert more cases not only this one and there are double IDs possible. Hence I like not to insert the ID in the query ..

For some reason which I do not understand why the autoincrement does not work correctly.

Comment: You probably ran some inserts bypassing the default value and thus the sequence is out of sync with the table's content. That's why using `generated always as identity` is the better solution for auto increment columns

Answer (score 0):

Using 'int GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY primary key' as for my issue helped.